# Last route was not proxy-passed as configured in nginx 19.x reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

There are 3 routes in the reverse proxy configuration. The one which doesn't work is the last route for `/(sokt|socket.io)`:

```
server {

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8545;
  }

  location /api {
    #rewrite /api/(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
  }

  location /(sokt|socket.io) { //<<==this route does not pass correctly
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  server_name mydomeain.top;
}
```

Here is the output of `access.log`:

```
xx.xx.131.199 - - [18/Feb/2022:08:09:27 +0800] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NyAANqy HTTP/1.1" 404 53 "-" "okhttp/4.9.1" "-""127.0.0.1:8545" "127.0.0.1:8545""-" "http_authorization"
xx.xx.131.199 - - [18/Feb/2022:08:09:32 +0800] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NyAAP7n HTTP/1.1" 404 53 "-" "okhttp/4.9.1" "-""127.0.0.1:8545" "127.0.0.1:8545""-" "http_authorization"
```

As we can see in the log, `/(sokt|socket.io)` is routed the same as `/` which passes to `localhost:8545` instead of `localhost:5000`. What is missing in the nginx reverse config?

Comment: You should use `~` (case-sensitive) or `~*` (case-insensitive) location modifier if you want a regex pattern matching location: `location ~ ^/(sokt|socket.io) { ... }`

Comment: `~ ^/` works. Many thanks. But I don't quite understand why there needs a regex match here since it is an exact match. I will vote if you want to put it into an answer.

Comment: An exact match location is defined using the `=` modifier, e.g.: `location = /socket.io { ... }`